# Getting part of nginx url as "variable"?

Tags: configuration, nginx, config

I currently have this rule in my `nginx` config:

```
location /tun {
proxy_pass         http://url.domain.com/mp3.mp3;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```

Which i use for tunneling in a private project. However, i want to make it dynamic.

I am looking for something like this:

```
location /tun/$URL$ {
proxy_pass         $URL$;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```

So users can type in their own url's like that.

I understand there are security flaws in this, but i really want to see this happening!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location ~* ^/tun/(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$1;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: Gives me a `500 internal server` error. I'll try play around with it though, thanks!

Comment: Add http://$1. If you are proxying to external domain, includes resolver 8.8.8.8;

Comment: Note this will fail if your URL contains spaces. NGINX has an unacknowledged bug where the incoming `/url%20with%20spaces` will result in `$1` = `/url with spaces` and this is passed unencoded to proxy_pass as `/url with spaces` which will never work.